# Excel VBA dividing decimals causes answer to be 100x too big

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a weird problem when trying divide by a number with decimals in Excel VBA (2016)

```
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim result As Double

a = 0.55
b = 16.8

result = a / b

MsgBox (result)
MsgBox (0.55 / 16.8)
```

Both msgboxes display 3.2738....the correct answer should be 0.0327....

If I remove the decimal place from b, making the calculation 0.55 / 16 it shows the correct answer of 0.0343...

The act of dividing by a decimal number appears to make the answer 100x too big.

Whats going on?

I've tried the same thing VB.NET on my PC and it works correctly so I dont think it's a system/locale issue.

Comment: Did you not notice the `E-02` on the end: `3.27380952380952E-02`?

Comment: i did, I assumed that was just because the numbers went on forever, I suspect your going to tell me othrwise though....

Comment: `E-02` is equivalent to `*10^-2`, i.e. `3.27380952380952E-02` is equivalent to `0.0327380952380952`, by moving the decimal point two places to the left. So there's no error/problem at all. More reading under `E Notation` in [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: I did not know that, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a more intuitive result:

```
Sub qwerty()

    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim result As Double
    
    a = 0.55
    b = 16.8
    
    result = a / b
    
    MsgBox (Format(result, "0.000000"))

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Nope its not giving you a very big result its just not rounding the answer off

try this

```
  Dim a As Double
  Dim b As Double
  Dim result As Double

  a = 0.55
  b = 16.8

  result = a / b

  MsgBox (Round(result, 10))
```